# How to add checkout fields in magento 2 and save them in db

Tags: magento

I need to add some fields to the shipping address form from checkout page, and then save them in db.
I developed a module ( link to download: https://github.com/rlaa/custom-checkout-fields/blob/master/Test_attr.zip).

Steps to install it:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Delete all files in the pub/static/frontend and var/view_preprocessing directories.

When I click next button , custom checkout field is not sent in post request.

I don't know why this is happening.